# Pull last 3 charecters from Regex positive lookhead match

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, positive-lookahead

I have the following regex expression `^.*?(?=\.)` and i'm looking to modify it so that i can pull the 3 charecter country code (**bold**) from a given path.  Right now the regex just creates a group before the period.

/path/to/folder/Conclusions_Pakistan_2019-09-13_**PAK**.pdf

regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/FGjqSl/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `^.*?(?=\.)` matches everything from start until it asserts presence of `.` hence it matches too much.

You may just use this regex 3 character country code comprising all upper case letters:

```
[A-Z]{3}(?=\.)
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGjqSl/2)